# Extract latitude and longitude from rotated coordinate system

Tags: netcdf, xarray

I'm new to working with geographic data so please bear with me.

I have the following data:

```
bnds,projection_x_coordinate,projection_y_coordinate,realization,fog_area_fraction,lambert_azimuthal_equal_area,projection_y_coordinate_bnds,projection_x_coordinate_bnds,forecast_period,forecast_reference_time,time
0,-1158000.0,-1036000.0,12,0.0,-2147483647,-1037000.0,-1159000.0,1 days 06:00:00.000000000,2019-03-22 19:00:00,2019-03-24 01:00:00
0,-1158000.0,-1036000.0,13,0.0,-2147483647,-1037000.0,-1159000.0,1 days 06:00:00.000000000,2019-03-22 19:00:00,2019-03-24 01:00:00
0,-1158000.0,-1036000.0,14,0.0,-2147483647,-1037000.0,-1159000.0,1 days 06:00:00.000000000,2019-03-22 19:00:00,2019-03-24 01:00:00
0,-1158000.0,-1034000.0,12,0.0,-2147483647,-1035000.0,-1159000.0,1 days 06:00:00.000000000,2019-03-22 19:00:00,2019-03-24 01:00:00
```

from which I would like to determine the appropriate lat/long coordinates. Note that the data is in the RotatedGeogCS format and I have x- and y-projections along with a data value for "Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area" projection.

Does anyone know how to convert from the given data to what I want? Is that even the appropriate question to ask here? The end goal is to present the fog_area_fraction data within the region it has been calculated for.

For those curious this data was extracted from the [MOGREPS-UK](https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/research/weather/ensemble-forecasting/mogreps) dataset from AWS, processed using libraries for netCDF, xarray and Iris and then dumped to CSV.

EDIT: Here's a sample of the cube in the original form:

```
    Dimensions:                       (bnds: 2, projection_x_coordinate: 1042, projection_y_coordinate: 970, realization: 3)
Coordinates:
  * realization                   (realization) int32 12 13 14
  * projection_y_coordinate       (projection_y_coordinate) float32 -1036000.0 ... 902000.0
  * projection_x_coordinate       (projection_x_coordinate) float32 -1158000.0 ... 924000.0
    forecast_period               timedelta64[ns] ...
    forecast_reference_time       datetime64[ns] ...
    time                          datetime64[ns] ...
Dimensions without coordinates: bnds
Data variables:
    fog_area_fraction             (realization, projection_y_coordinate, projection_x_coordinate) float32 ...
    lambert_azimuthal_equal_area  int32 ...
    projection_y_coordinate_bnds  (projection_y_coordinate, bnds) float32 ...
    projection_x_coordinate_bnds  (projection_x_coordinate, bnds) float32 ...
Attributes:
    history:                      2019-03-22T22:54:56Z: StaGE Decoupler
    institution:                  Met Office
    mosg__forecast_run_duration:  PT126H
    mosg__grid_domain:            uk_extended
    mosg__grid_type:              standard
    mosg__grid_version:           2.1.0
    mosg__model_configuration:    uk_ens
    source:                       Met Office Unified Model
    title:                        MOGREPS-UK Model Forecast on UK 2 km Standa...
    um_version:                   11.1
    Conventions:                  CF-1.5, UKMO-1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using the MOGREPS-UK data on AWS.

The following code will plot MOGREPS-UK data for a single ensemble member (AKA 'realization'), with a map of coastlines and latitude & longitude tick labels.

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Open dataset.
ds = xr.open_dataset(NETCDF_FILENAME)

# Instantiate a Coordinate Reference System (CRS) object for MOGREPS-UK.
central_latitude = ds.lambert_azimuthal_equal_area.latitude_of_projection_origin[0]
central_longitude = ds.lambert_azimuthal_equal_area.longitude_of_projection_origin[0]
mogreps_crs = ccrs.LambertAzimuthalEqualArea(
    central_latitude=central_latitude,
    central_longitude=central_longitude)

# Plot with coastlines.
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()) # Use lat/lon coordinates.
ax.coastlines(resolution='10m')
ds.isel(realization=0)['fog_area_fraction'].plot(
    ax=ax, add_colorbar=False, transform=mogreps_crs)
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but I don't reputation to add it.

According to [this help page](http://data.informaticslab.co.uk/mogreps_data_basics.html) MOGREPS data comes in a lat/lon grid:

```
import iris
mydata = iris.load("./prods_op_mogreps-uk_20130101_03_00_003.nc")
print(mydata)
(...)
11: fog_area_fraction / (1)             (time: 4; grid_latitude: 548; grid_longitude: 421)
```

Can't you keep those data during prepprocessing?

Comment: The data that I extracted doesn't have it in that form.